# How to retrieve items with hibernate clustered by to_days + COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date

I am pretty new to hibernate again, so this might be a noobish question ;).

Without to_days, but clustered by timestamp it works like this:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
    Root<Session> sessionRoot = query.from(Session.class);
    query.multiselect(
                sessionRoot.get("time").alias("time"),
                criteriaBuilder.count(sessionRoot).alias("count")
            );
    query.groupBy(sessionRoot.get("time"));
    List<Tuple> results = this.executeQuery(query);
```

So I recieve:

```
time|count
13721938721|1
13721938722|2
13721938723|3
13721938724|4
13721938725|2
13721938726|1
13721938727|4
```

But this are all sessioncounts for each millisecond, but I need those clustered by day and not by timestamp: thus I use to_days in plain mysql.

In mysql I perform this query:

```
SELECT TO_DAYS(`time`) AS `days`, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM sessions WHERE 1 GROUP BY `days`
```

This gives me:

```
days|count
777594|123
777595|60
777596|61
777597|74
```

But I have no idea, yet: how to achieve the same thing with javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder and CriteriaQuery in hibernate?

Comment: You should take a look at the query generated by hibernate, make sure it is being grouped by the alias and not the column name.

Comment: Also, i dont see any conversion to days in the criteria builder.

Comment: @Ziul This is right, because I don't know how to make this ;). How does one convert it to days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turned out, that HQL does not support TO_DAYS. Since I want to make it possible for MySQL and other databases, this is my final solution:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT concat(day(e.time), '-', month(e.time), '-', year(e.time)) AS days, COUNT(*) FROM Event e GROUP BY concat(day(e.time), '-', month(e.time), '-', year(e.time))");
```

The result is:

```
3-5-2012|980
4-5-2012|200
10-6-2012|123
12-6-2012|144
13-11-2012|500
```

So afterwards I convert all ugly date strings into proper milliseconds in java and have the data, which I need.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it with criteriaBuilder, but i do know how in Hibernate 4 criteria api:

```
query.setProjection(
    Projections.sqlProjection(
        "TO_DAYS(time) as days",
        new String[]{"days"},
        new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER}
    )
);
```

sqlProjection allows you to cast or convert data types, but careful, using a projection will only retrieve the fileds you specify in it, and the resulting list will come up like this:

```
 List<Object[]> results = this.executeQuery(query);
```

But you can make hibernate do a alias match with the properties using a result transformer:

```
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Session.class));
```

and the list comes out like it normally does:

```
List<Session.class> results = this.executeQuery(query);
```

Sorry i could not provide a criteriaBuilder solution, but i hope this gets you in the right track.

Comment: Thanks Ziul. It brought me on the right track!! I answered the question on my own now. Hopefully I didn't miss anything.